# Identify duplicate values in dictionary and print in a table

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary (d) where every key can have multiple values (appended as a list).

For example, dictionary has following two key,value pairs where one has duplicate values while other doesn't:

> SPECIFIC-THREATS , ['5 SPECIFIC-THREATS Microsoft Windows print
>   spooler little endian DoS attempt', '4 SPECIFIC-THREATS obfuscated
>   RealPlayer Ierpplug.dll ActiveX exploit attempt', '4 SPECIFIC-THREATS
>   obfuscated RealPlayer Ierpplug.dll ActiveX exploit attempt']

and

> TELNET , ['1 TELNET bsd exploit client finishing']

I want to go through the whole dictionary, check if any key has duplicate values and then print results in a table which has key, number of duplicate values, value (which appears multiple times) etc. as columns.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import texttable
import collections

def dupechecker():

 t = texttable.Texttable()
 for key, value in d.iteritems():
   for x, y in collections.Counter(value).items():
     if y > 1:
      t.add_rows([["Category", "Number of dupe values", "Value which appears multiple times"], [key, y, x]])
      print t.draw()
```

It works but the keys which do not have any duplicate values (i.e. TELNET in this case) wont appear in the table output (since the table is printed in the if condition statement). This is what I am getting:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|        Category         |  Number of dupe values  |   Value which appears   |
|                         |                         |     multiple times      |
+=========================+=========================+=========================+
| SPECIFIC-THREATS        | 2                       | 4 SPECIFIC-THREATS      |
|                         |                         | obfuscated RealPlayer   |
|                         |                         | Ierpplug.dll ActiveX    |
|                         |                         | exploit attempt         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Is there anyway with which I can keep track of interesting parameters (no. of duplicate values and value which appears multiple times) for each key and then print them together. I want the output to be like:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|        Category         |  Number of dupe values  |   Value which appears   |
|                         |                         |     multiple times      |
+=========================+=========================+=========================+
| SPECIFIC-THREATS        | 2                       | 4 SPECIFIC-THREATS      |
|                         |                         | obfuscated RealPlayer   |
|                         |                         | Ierpplug.dll ActiveX    |
|                         |                         | exploit attempt         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| TELNET                  | 0                       |                         |
|                         |                         |                         |
|                         |                         |                         |
|                         |                         |                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**UPDATE**

Resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `dupechecker` to add rows also for "non-duplicates", but only once per category, add the header before the loop and print the table when you are done.

```
def dupechecker():

 t = texttable.Texttable()
 t.header(["Category", "Number of dupe values", "Value which appears multiple times"])
 for key, value in d.iteritems():
   has_dupe = False
   for x, y in collections.Counter(value).items():
     if y > 1:
      has_dupe = True
      t.add_row([key, y, x])
   if not has_dupe:
      t.add_row([key, 0, ''])
 print t.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks. Close but this would output an extra row for the case when the value is not a duplicate for key 'SPECIFIC-THREATS'. See my edit above.

Comment: I was about to comment that I figured it out. Basically doing something similar to the check you have used. Cheers